# multiplying a string with a number

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How could i multiply a string by a number to achieve n amount of repetitions of that string in a Labels caption, i.e 
   if n = 5 then 's'*n= 'sssss' which would then become the labels caption.

anything along those lines returns the error that the operator is not applicable to the operand type.
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no built in operator that does what you want. Your code would work in Python, but not in Delphi.

If your string is a single character then you can use [`StringOfChar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StringOfChar):

```
Caption := StringOfChar('s', n);
```

For a longer input string use [`DupeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.DupeString) from the `StrUtils` unit:

```
Caption := DupeString('blah', n);
```

Comment: @WarrenP I didn't know it was there either, but I guessed there would be something and a quick search for `count` in `StrUtils` revealed it!

Answer (score 6):

Delphi does not allow that syntax. However, there is a function called `DupeString`, in `StrUtils.pas` that amounts to the same thing:

```
Label1.Caption := DupeString('test', 4);
```